# how to setup a function in my code as it's own stateful widget and then pass variables to it

Tags: flutter, dart

I have written the below code and it is working as intended. when a button is pressed, a string variable (displayText) is updated with the text from the button. then, the function UpdateWidget reads the displayText string and use a switch/case to determine what further buttons to display, then when those new buttons are pressed, it saves the selection as the switchtext String.

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  String displayText = '';
  String switchText = '';
  var displayWidget = Container();

  void updateWidget(String displayText) {
    switch (displayText) {
      case 'Option A':
        displayWidget = Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Button(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchText = val;
                      print(switchText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option 1'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Button(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchText = val;
                      print(switchText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option 2'),
            ],
          ),
        );
        break;
      case 'Option B':
        displayWidget = Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Button(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchText = val;
                      print(switchText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option 3'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Button(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchText = val;
                      print(switchText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option 4'),
            ],
          ),
        );
        break;

      default:
        displayWidget = Container();
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 100,
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Button(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      displayText = val;
                      updateWidget(val!);
                      print(displayText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option A'),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Button(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      displayText = val;
                      updateWidget(val!);
                      print(displayText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option B')
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
          ),
          displayWidget,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  Button({required this.color, required this.onTap, required this.text});

  final Color color;
  final String text;
  final ValueChanged? onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          if (onTap != null) {
            onTap!(text);
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          color: color,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

What I would like to do and I was hoping someone would be able to show me please, is how do I turn the
UpdateWidget function into it's own stateful class and then pass the string displayText to it so it knows what further buttons to display? when it is called upon. I would then need those further buttons to update the switchText string when they are pressed please.

thank you so much and any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `displayText` and `onTap` function, you can create this class:

```
class DisplayWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(String)? onTap;
  final String displayText;
  const DisplayWidget({Key? key, required this.displayText, this.onTap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (displayText) {
      case 'Option A':
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Button(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  onTap: onTap,
                  text: 'Option 1'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Button(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onTap: onTap,
                  text: 'Option 2'),
            ],
          ),
        );
      case 'Option B':
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Button(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchText = val;
                      print(switchText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option 3'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Button(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  onTap: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      switchText = val;
                      print(switchText);
                    });
                  },
                  text: 'Option 4'),
            ],
          ),
        );

      default:
        return Container();
    }
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 100,
      ),
      Row(
        children: [
          Button(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  displayText = val;
                  print(displayText);
                });
              },
              text: 'Option A'),
          SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Button(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  displayText = val;
                  print(displayText);
                });
              },
              text: 'Option B')
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 30,
      ),
      DisplayWidget(displayText: displayText,
             onTap:(val){
                 setState(() {
                  switchText = val;
                  print(switchText);
                 });
             }),
    ],
  ),
);
```

and also change your `Button` class to this:

```
class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  Button({required this.color, required this.onTap, required this.text});

  final Color color;
  final String text;
  final Function(String)? onTap; // <-- change this
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          if (onTap != null) {
            onTap!(text);
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 100,
          color: color,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. i'm now getting the following error on the onTap. The argument type 'dynamic Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)?'.

Comment: also I have one question in your Button class why did you define onTap nullable but in constructor used required?

Comment: Thanks so much @eamirho3ein I'm not sure. it was a piece of code shared as an answer when I was trying to pass whatever the string text in the button was set to out so it could be used in a string in my stateful widget